# -e disappeared in environment variable, how to avoid this?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS='-e EXTERNAL_PORT=443'

echo $OPTS

cat 1.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo $OPTS
    exit 1
fi
```

in this case, I got output:

```
EXTERNAL_PORT=443
cat: 1.txt: No such file or directory
EXTERNAL_PORT=443
```

if I change OPTS to

```
OPTS='a -e EXTERNAL_PORT=443'
```

now it worked as normal

```
a -e EXTERNAL_PORT=443
cat: 1.txt: No such file or directory
a -e EXTERNAL_PORT=443
```

How can I avoid this? And this is a simplified demo, in my real cases, I have an environment variable OPTS starts with -e.

I echo it, it is correct, but after line `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then`, the "-e" disappeared, this causes bug for my scripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Try double quoting your variable (eg. `echo "$OPTS"`) ...

Comment: @l'L'l The problem is not the shell, it is how `echo` interprets its arguments. Quotes won't help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` is interpreting the `-e` as a command option meaning that it should interpret any escape sequences in the string to be printed, rather than as part of the string to be printed. `echo` has a number of "features" that can cause unexpected trouble (and worse, different versions of `echo` implement different options). Try this instead:

```
$ OPTS='-e EXTERNAL_PORT=443'
$ printf '%s\n' "$OPTS"
-e EXTERNAL_PORT=443
```

BTW, storing command options in a plain string won't work if any of them have spaces (or sometimes any shell wildcards, or...). It's better to use an array for them, and then double-quote the array reference to keep the shell from messing with it. It's also best to use lowercase (or mixed case) variable names to avoid conflicts with the special variables used by the shell and other programs (they're all uppercase):

```
$ opts=(-e EXTERNAL_PORT=443 -e COMMENT="This is a test")
$ printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}"
-e
EXTERNAL_PORT=443
-e
COMMENT=This is a test
```